# The wrong record in my database is getting updated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

im using laravel eloquent to update a record in a database table. Im passing in a parameter of 52 which is the id of the record I want to update (primary key).

I am printing the query to check which record its finding and its printing the record with the id of 13 and then when i check the table, id 13 has been updated.

```
protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
protected $table = 'todo';

public $timestamps = false;

public static function complete($todoId, $userId)
{
    $now = new DateTime();

    $query = Self::join('todoTypes', 'todo.typeId', 'todoTypes.id')
                 ->where('todoTypes.canComplete', 1)
                 ->whereNull('todo.completedDate')
                 ->find(52);

    $query->where(function ($query) use ($now)
    {
       $query->whereNull('cancelDate')
             ->orWhere('cancelDate', '>', $now);
    });

    if ($query)
    {
        $query->completedDate = $now;
        $query->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your Model class to a better understanding. At first sight, I can see you are using the find method in a query builder. I believe the best approach is to use ->where('id',52)->get()->first().

Comment: I have updated it to show the model. Even when I do what you said its getting the record with the id of 13, I just tried adding a 'select' at the start, at then it gets the right id, very strange

Comment: You tried to use where('id',52)->get()->first() instead of ->find(52)?
When you call methods like join or select, the return is a QueryBuilder instance based on your model. I believe your issue is there.

Comment: Yes ive tried this and it gives the same result. I have found the id is always 13 regardless of what I pick but the other information is returns is correct, so i think theres something wrong with the join. If i take out the where and join, it works

Answer (score 2):

How about trying like this?

The query after using find did not make any sense since find returns the first object not a query builder instance.

```
public static function complete($todoId, $userId)
{
    $now = new DateTime();

    $object = Self::join('todoTypes', 'todo.typeId', 'todoTypes.id')
        ->where('todoTypes.canComplete', 1)
        ->whereNull('todo.completedDate')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($now) {
            $query->whereNull('cancelDate')
                ->orWhere('cancelDate', '>', $now);
        })->find(52);

    if ($object) {
        $object->completedDate = $now;
        $object->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I thought that the use of find is not a good way, but your snnipet is nice.

Comment: Still gives the same result, I have tried lots of different ids and they all return id 13 but the other table fields correspond with the correct Id. I think the problem has something to do with the join. If i take out there where, and join, it works

Comment: @WillDaniels For better debugging can you show what calling `toSql()` method returns? (call it before the ->find(52)) it will turn the query to a raw sql string.

Comment: @naamhierzo i did that and it gave the correct result when i pasted the query into my database.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this by just adding a select at the start

```
select('todo.id', 'todo.completedDate')
```

It seems it was getting the right row, but displaying the id as something else.
When I took out the join and the joins where clause, it worked. I suspect it was using the id of the joint row from the todoTypes table as that was 13.